# Selected value in a list

Tags: php

I'm trying to show the selected value in the list if it's found matching. It's successfully populated but the selected value code does not run.

```
Code:
$StaffName = 'Jimmy Chan';
<select name="Staff" id="Staff"><?php
$data = array();
$data[0] = '';
echo "<option value='" . $data[0] . "'>" . $data[0] . "</option>";
$result= $DB->query('select No, FirstName, LastName from Staff');
foreach ($result as $data)
{
    $SNo = $data['No'];
    $SFN = $data['FirstName'];
    $SLN = $data['LastName'];
    $SName = $SFN.' '.$SLN;         

    if($SName == $StaffName)
    {
        echo "<option value='".$Sno."' selected = \"selected\">".$Sname."</option>\n";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "<option value='" .$SNo. "'>" . $SName . " </option>";
    }

}                 
?>
        </select>
```

The second else statement do run but not the if statement. I have already put the "selected" inside. Kindly advise.

Comment: @JLearner i think you need to set selected="selected" ..var dump the two $StaffName, $SName to know what actually is coming

Comment: try this if(strtilower(trim($SName))==strtilower(trim($$StaffName))), if you don't want match case sensitive

Comment: sorry missing selected. Already have tat selected="selected" inside my code acutally. But it still doesnt selected. #hraval will try

Comment: Please replace `$Sno` and `$Sname` with `$SNo` and `$SName` in selected option code line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($result as $data)
{
    $SNo = $data['No'];
    $SFN = $data['FirstName'];
    $SLN = $data['LastName'];
    $SName = trim($SFN).' '.trim($SLN);         
    if(strtolower($SName) == strtolower($StaffName))
    {
        echo "<option value='".$Sno."' selected = 'selected'>".$Sname."</option>\n";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<option value='" .$SNo. "'>".$SName."</option>\n";
    }
}
```

Also, you have $Sname instead of $SName in first "if" statement. I am not sure if PHP can make a difference on it, but just keep in mind.
The same for $Sno and $SNo variables.

Comment: thanks you have done a great help. I think it's my upper case and lower case that causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the problem is with the value in variable $SName. Before comparison trim and convert both variables to uppercase or lowercase.

Lower case: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php

Uppercase: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Trim: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Also try,

```
echo "<option value='".$Sno."' selected="selected">".$Sname."</option>"; //remove \n
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
echo "<option value='".$Sno."' selected = \"selected\">".$Sname."</option>\n";
```

But Variable names are `$SNo` and `$SName` and you are using `$Sno` and `$Sname`. So Please replace line with line given below.

```
echo "<option value='".$SNo."' selected = \"selected\">".$SName."</option>\n";
```

I hope i will be work for you,

thanks